# Show / Hide custom php field with title

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, logic

I want to display a custom field we have [using the Estatik wordpress real estate plugin] if the database field has a value and hide that if it is empty. I can get the field to display and hide if empty or filled out, but, I cannot display the text: "Year built" when the year is filled out:

```
<?php if( es_the_property_field('year-built1594411179f5f08c8ab6ff14') ): ?>
    <p>Year built: <?php es_the_property_field('year-built1594411179f5f08c8ab6ff14'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What can i change the code above to achieve:

If the year is filled out, I'd like it to display:
Year built: 1994

If the year is left empty, i'd like the paragraph to not print at all

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most data in WordPress, there are `the_[…]()` and `get_the_[…]()` style functions. Generally the `the_` functions will ***output*** the data, and the `get_the_` functions will ***return***. Most plugins and themes have similar functionality. I downloaded the demo Estatik plugin and noticed that it does have that functionality as well.

In your `if` statement, you're actually outputting the year field there, and it's not returning a truthy value, so it stops there (otherwise it would show `1994Year Built: 1994`).

The returning function is `es_get_the_property_field( $field, $post_id = 0 );`

So, coupling that with a little bit of cleanup (utilizing the before/after arguments of `es_the_property_field`, you would end up with something like this:

```
<?php if( es_get_the_property_field('year-built1594411179f5f08c8ab6ff14') ){
    es_the_property_field('year-built1594411179f5f08c8ab6ff14', '<p>Year built: ', '</p>' );
} ?>
```

*HOWEVER:*

Here's the whole markup for the `es_the_property_field()` function:

```
/**
 * Render property field.
 *
 * @param $field
 * @param string $before
 * @param string $after
 */
function es_the_property_field( $field, $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    $result = es_get_the_property_field( $field );

    echo ! empty( $result ) ? $before . $result . $after : null;
}
```

This means you could actually drop your `if` statement altogether, because that function checks to see if it's empty for you. So you could simplify it even further to just:

```
<?php es_the_property_field( 'year-built1594411179f5f08c8ab6ff14', '<p>Year Built: ', '</p>' ); ?>
```

> Note: I don't have any personal experience with this plugin, this is all just based on what I found in the `estatik/functions.php` file.

Comment: Here is the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Estatik theme but I can tell you that you could test the content like this.

```
<?php 

$year_built = es_property_field('year-built1594411179f5f08c8ab6ff14');
if( $year_built != "" || $year_built != false ): ?>
    <p>Year built: <?php echo date("Y", strtotime ($year_built)); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So the two things you were missing was a proper test in the if statement and then echoing out the year_built with the date format. Now this is assuming a few things.

1. that es_the_property_field echos instead of returning which would be a very wordpress thing to do
2. that removing the "the" from that function is the version of that function that returns instead of echos.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't end up testing out because @xhynk's answer did the trick, but thank you SO much!